# Notify me for a specific location or straight road google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, location, latitude-longitude

I'm getting my current Lat Long from fused
I want to notify my user when he/ she comes on a specific route

In the below i have share you a location which is Yamuna express way
I want to show notification to user when user comes on this highway from any side or any where

please answer properly, I'm really in the need of answer

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9ktO.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should know "specific route" coordinates and periodically check does the current user position lays on route. If you use [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview) you can get route coordinates from [Directions API response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#DirectionsRoute), if you need specific street you can add its coordinates manually (or download them from e.g. [OpenStreetMap](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/5107/find-street-coordinates)).

For checking whether the current user position lies on or near a "specific route" polyline, you can use [`isLocationOnPath`](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#isLocationOnPath-LatLng-java.util.List-boolean-double-) method from [PolyUtil](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility) library:

```
public static boolean isLocationOnPath(LatLng point,
                                       java.util.List<LatLng> polyline,
                                       boolean geodesic,
                                       double tolerance)
```

where `point` - current user coordinates, `polyline` - list of "specific route" coordinates, `geodesic` - map modes (set it to `true`) and `tolerance` - maximal distance (in meters) between "specific road" and user coordinates when user still considered "on the specific route"

For reducing power (and traffic) consumption you can add some [geofences](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing) along the route (or better only on crossroads where user can enter the route) and track user location precisely only if user within one of geofences:

[image: Geofences along the target road]